# how to upgrade ffmpeg to latest version in centos 5.11?

Tags: centos, ffmpeg

I have CentoS 5.11 installed. 
and ffmpeg 0.10.2 [

```
[root@cs1590 ~]# ffmpeg
   ffmpeg version 0.10.2.git Copyright (c) 2000-2012 the FFmpeg developers
  built on Jun  5 2012 08:51:26 with gcc 4.1.2 20080704 (Red Hat 4.1.2-51)
  configuration: --enable-gpl --enable-libx264
  libavutil      51. 56.100 / 51. 56.100
  libavcodec     54. 23.100 / 54. 23.100
  libavformat    54.  6.101 / 54.  6.101
  libavdevice    54.  0.100 / 54.  0.100
  libavfilter     2. 78.100 /  2. 78.100
  libswscale      2.  1.100 /  2.  1.100
  libswresample   0. 15.100 /  0. 15.100
  libpostproc    52.  0.100 / 52.  0.100
Hyper fast Audio and Video encoder
]
```

I want to update ffmpeg to the latest version.
Please tell me the detailed steps to do it.

Comment: If you do a web search you should find the CentOS compilation guide: https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/CompilationGuide/Centos

Answer (score 1):

The best way to use current ffmpeg on Linux is to download a static build from [this download site](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

I typically

- either uninstall distro-provided ffmpeg and put it where the distro's version would be
- or put it somewhere in the path where it is found earlier than the distro version
- or just call it with the full path

Answer (score 0):

As suggested in [@eugen-rieck's answer](https://superuser.com/a/874459/20568) I too would use the static build as provided by [johnvansickle's website](http://johnvansickle.com/ffmpeg/).

I typically install it here:

```
$HOME/bin/ffmpeg-git-32bit-static
```

and then override in my `.bashrc` file my `$PATH` like so:

```
export PATH=$HOME/bin/ffmpeg-git-32bit-static:$PATH
```

I will warn you however that these static builds seem to require additional capabilities from the Linux kernel that are not present.

For example, when trying to use `youtube-dl` with it:

```
[pbs] 2365100759: Downloading m3u8 information
FATAL: kernel too old
FATAL: kernel too old
[download] Destination: Nature - Saving Otter 501-2365100759.mp4
FATAL: kernel too old
FATAL: kernel too old
FATAL: kernel too old


ERROR: ffmpeg exited with code -11
```